# How to change ip on the fly without knowing current device

Tags: linux, networking, archlinux

I'm on ArchLinux and I want to change on the fly (whithout config file change) the ip address of my current connection.
The command:

```
ip addr add 192.168.1.57 dev wlan0
```

seems to be good but I don’t know the current device (wlan0, eth0).

I need to do this from a boot script. I can't check manualy what is the current used device.

Someone would have an idea for me?

Thanks !

Comment: If you know current IP (not a device) you can find/parse device name. Use "ifconfig" command for all devices info, parse output for the sake of device name and change IP for this session by "ifconfig <device_name> 192.168.1.5" f.e.

Comment: No, I don't know IP. This script will be used by a large number of Raspberry Pi. The IP's will come from a centralised data file.

Comment: Both net devices can be in work at the same time or only one of it?

Comment: 99% - Only one. 
Or, if both, I need to change only one, no matter which.
The purpose of this is to contact the RPi easily.

Comment: You need to find active device at first. Look at ifconfig packet counters (parse it) several times - inactive net device don`t send and don`t receive anything. After that you know your device name and can change it IP with ifconfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ip link show
```

gives you a list of interfaces, with their status:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp6s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
25: enp0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

You just need to check which one says `state UP` (in case of Ethernet, it means that the cable is connected, for wireless, it means that the network is associated). In shell, you would do:

```
interface="`ip link show | awk '/state UP/ { gsub(/:/, "", $2); print $2; exit }'`"
ip addr add 192.168.1.57 dev "$interface"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with "ExecUpPost" on my profiles /etc/netctl like that:

```
ExecUpPost='ip addr add $(</var/varIP) dev wlan0 || true'
```

because I know the device on each profil... but I can't control a config change (/var/varIP) on the fly.

drinkcat answere allow more flexibility. Thanks.